# how to make Taglist window cannot be placed by opened file

Tags: vim

I like Taglist in  Vim very much. However, when I open a new file or click the file name in the BufferExplor, the file will display in the Taglist window. Is there method to keep the Taglist window cannot be used to display the file opened? When I open a file, how to use a new window in the Vim?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you're inside the TagList window, don't use `:edit`. Either use a command list `:split` or `:vsplit` to open the file, or move to another window first (via `<C-W><C-W>` etc.) The typical layout is a small TagList sidebar to the left, and a big editing area right of it. Move there first.

As to plugins like BufferExplorer, they either need to be able to recognize those "special" windows, or again you have to use the "open in split window" command in them. I personally use custom mappings to toggle such plugins, so that there is only one at a time displayed in the sidebar, thereby avoiding this issue.